# How to install two versions of Cocoapods on Mac OSX

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

How to install two versions of Cocopads. Because I have a project that needs a specific Cocoapods version so the build targets would work fine. If I use a newer version of Cocoapods to install the frameworks, the project just won't build. So what's the solution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Gemfiles](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html) tend to be the solution to this, though it works per-project not per target. I don't think you're going to find an answer for different pod versions per target.

Comment: I want it to be like two ruby versions. I can switch ruby version back and fourth. Can we do that?

Comment: Gemfiles are one of the best answers here, it's how I deal with the problem. However, a really new tool came out for doing this: https://github.com/kylef/podenv allows switching between pod versions in the command line.